# Creating a project with Bitnami DjangoStack?

Tags: django, project

I just installed the Bitnami DjangoStack and want to know how to create a new project in Windows.

I tried opening the python.exe (similar to command prompt) and tried typing in:

django-admin.py startproject testproject which is what many articles seem to say to start with.

I am getting an invalid syntax error. Do I need to do something else? Eager to get started!

Answer (score 1):

django-admin.py is a shell command, not a python statement. Issue it in a cmd window.

Make sure the path to django-admin.py is in your environment variables or in PYTHONPATH. Since this is a special DjangoStack distribution I guess it's in there.

Comment: Correct. Just start the command prompt found in the Windows start menu Django entry, it will have the environment pre-configured